# Capture the full decimal number from an hours tracking string

Tags: regex

I have content like this:

```
2015 11-20 -- #TU 10:30-6 (7.5 hrs)
2015 11-19 -- #TU 10-11; 1-7 (7 hrs)
2015 11-18 -- #TU 9:30-4 (6.5 hrs)
```

I'd like to capture hours for this month and customer code.

I use this to match all lines that start with this month:

```
\2015 11-.*#TU
```

And then added this, with the intent to capture one or more chars that match `\d` digits or the literal `.`:

```
\2015 11-.*#TU.*([\d\.]+)\g
```

...I tried some other variations too, but it only captures `7`, `7`, and `6`.

How can I capture `7.5`, `7`, and `6.5`?

You can try this at Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/hU3xA0/1

Comment: Use [`2015 11-.*?#TU.*?(\d+(\.\d+)?) hrs\)`](https://regex101.com/r/eN9xQ2/1) or better [`2015 11-.*?#TU.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) hrs\)`](https://regex101.com/r/eN9xQ2/2)

Comment: Modified a little to not capture the inner group and trap leading decimals that works great. Thanks @Tushar! `2015 11-.*?#WTR.*?((?:\.)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) hr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

`\2015 11-.*#TU.*\(([\d\.]+)\g`

**To explain what's going on**

The reason it's not working for you is because of that greedy `.*` after the `#TU`. A greedy quantifier will match as many characters as it possibly can, while allowing the rest of the expression to keep matching. The way your regex gets processed is a little unintuitive at first sight.

Take the following input as an example: `2015 11-20 -- #TU 10:30-6 (7.5 hrs)`

**Here's how you probably imagine your regex works on the string**

`2015 11-.*#TU.*` should match up to `2015 11-20 -- #TU 10:30-6 (`

and then

`([\d\.]+)` should match the `7.5`

**In fact, what happens is this**

`2015 11-.*#TU.*` matches `2015 11-20 -- #TU 10:30-6 (7.`

and then

`([\d\.]+)` matches the `5`

**Why does my example work?**

Because I've specified a literal `(` character to terminate the greedy quantifier. Instead of saying "match as much as you can as long as you end before the last digit," we're saying "match as much as you can until you hit a `(` character and then match at least one digit or dot.

**Bonus improvement**

`2015 11-.*#TU.*\((\d+(\.\d+)?)`

Here, I've changed you character class `[\d\.]` into `\d+(\.\d+)?`. This is a stricter match because you'll find it won't match erroneous input like `2015 11-20 -- #TU 10:30-6 (...1.23... hrs)` or `2015 11-20 -- #TU 10:30-6 (.5 hrs)` for example. Of course, I'm assuming that half an hour would be expressed as `0.5` and not `.5`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. It's good to have a solution, but even better to get some understanding along the way.